# spring boot, is it possible to translate mvn based documentation and examples to gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle

I used gradle for years with grails, but you rarely have to touch it.
With spring boot, you can create either mvn or gradle based project.
however, 99.9% of documentation on spring boot only gives "how to" in the form of MVN commands.  Im no maven expert.

If I want to go with gradle, but need to follow a tutorial or how-to which uses mvn, is there an easy way to translate between the two, or should I just go with mvn to start with, and give up on gradle features such as incremental compilation (which saves a huge amount of time).

Answer (score 1):

First I want to say that there are a plethora of examples of how to use Spring with Gradle, and I think all of the Spring documentation has examples in using both Gradle and Maven. It would help to know if you are looking for a specific example.

If you need to translate a maven build to gradle, the best resource might be [Migrating Builds From Apache Maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html).

Gradle and Maven are very different beasts. Maven has a strict [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and plugins attach themselves to one of the stages to be executed. A plugin in maven-speak can be seen as a Task in gradle.

Gradle uses a different approach in which any task can be run at any point by changing the order of dependencies. It's a lot more flexible, which means each build could be running in a wildly different way.